# Botão sempre retornando o último ID

Tags: php

estou fazendo um sistema, eu preciso que ele verifique o ID do botão que foi clicado na tabela e execute a ação, porém ele sempre está pegando o último id, alguém sabe o que pode ser?

```php
if(isset($_SESSION["mensagemreset1"])):
    print $_SESSION["mensagemreset1"];
    unset($_SESSION["mensagemreset1"]);
endif;

$id = $_SESSION['idlogin'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `char` WHERE account_id='$id'";
$sql = $pdo->query($sql);

foreach ($sql->fetchAll() as $row) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['base_level']."/".$row['job_level']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['class']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['guild_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td><button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-sm'>Resetar Aparência</button> <button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-sm'>Resetar Posição<br></button></td>";

    echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$row['char_id']."></td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

**resetar_aparência.php:**

```php
include 'config.php';
require 'Usuario.class.php';

global $pdo;
global $char_id;

echo  $_POST['id'];

$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `char` SET hair=1, hair_color=1, clothes_color=1 WHERE char_id = '$char_id'");

$statement->execute();
//header("Location: inicio.php?pg=meuspersonagens");
$_SESSION['mensagemreset1'] = "<div class='sufee-alert alert with-close alert-success alert-dismissible fade show'>
  Aparência do personagem resetada com sucesso.
  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
    <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
  </button>
  </div>";
```

Coloquei o echo apenas para testar, porém ele sempre me retorna o último ID.

Comment: Confere o fechamentos das tuas tags HTML, antes e depois do seu `foreach`, confira também via inspetor de elementos se não tem nenhum erro do php sendo printando no meio do seu html;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embora você tenha um botão do tipo `submit` em cada linha não há qualquer formulário no código apresentado. O mais provável é que você tenha esquecido de adicionar esta parte à pergunta, caso contrário seu código não chamaria `resetar_aparência.php`.

Desconsiderando este detalhe, o problema é que os botões `Resetar Aparência` são do tipo submit sempre farão o envio do formulário. Sendo assim, adicione um formulário (tag `form`) para cada linha da sua tabela. Com isso, o botão será sempre específico de um único formulário.

```php
foreach ($sql->fetchAll() as $row) {
    echo "<tr><form method=\"POST\" action=\"resetar_aparência.php\">";
    (...)
    echo "</form></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Não é preciso agradecer, @RafaelRenan. Basta aceitar / fazer up vote da resposta ;) Esse comentário provavelmente será excluído...